# Вывести посты за последние 30 дней

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите понять куда этот код вставлять, чтобы выводились посты за последние 30 дней

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // за последние 30 дней
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй через WP_Query($args).
А в $args есть 'date_query', в него и пишешь :

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'order'=>'DESC',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'date_query' => array(
 array(
 'after' => '-30 days',
 ),
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал через фильтр, а как теперь мне сделать, чтоб кнопка(раньше появлялась когда на странице было 25 постов) теперь появлялась когда вывелись посты за последние 30 дней?